# How to make a generic of a class is required?

Tags: typescript

The class is:

```
class Test<P> {
  constructor(data: P) {}
}
```

I hope the following code does not pass the type check because it has no incoming generic:

```
new Test({ a: 1 })
```

I know that the generic P above is automatically derived as `{a: number}`, but this is not what I want, the following is.

```
new Test< {a: number} >({ a: 1 })
```

I tried a lot of methods, but in the end the generic P will be automatically derived into the constructor's parameter type.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173191/typescript-require-generic-parameter-to-be-provided) the first link on google "typescript require generic"

Comment: But the answer in that question is not for me.

Comment: I re-opened the question, while the same technique  can be applied it is not straight forward since the type parameter is used in the parameters. @aweiu next time it is helpful to explain why the answer does not satisfy your needs. You will find people on the ts tag generally reasonable and willing to listen 

Comment: Thanks a lot!I I got it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a question that deals with a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51173191/typescript-require-generic-parameter-to-be-provided):

```
async function get<U = void>(url: string & (U extends void ? "You must provide a type parameter" : string)): Promise<U> {
    return null as any;
}
```

The difference is that in that case the type parameter was not used in the parameters at all. This means typescript had no place to infer it the type parameter from. If, as in your case the type parameter is used in the argument list, typescript will use the argument as a source to infer the type parameter from and our trick of using the default value as a signal that no type parameter was explicitly specified will not work (since typescript not use the default if it can infer the type parameter).

The solution is simple enough, let typescript know that we don't want it to infer `T` from a specific parameter. While there is no builtin support to do this jcalz offers a reasonable workaround [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546)

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];
class Test<P = void> {
  constructor(data: NoInfer<P> & (P extends void ? "No type parameter was supplied" : {})) {}
}

new Test({ a: " "}) // err Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void & "No type parameter was supplied"'.
new Test<{ a: string }>({ a: " "})// ok
```

[play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAQyRCgH4oAGKAFxQkEAG4YyAbgBQAYwA2rJi2wQmwTAAVCUUXACWDfAG9pUKLLhJ16AK6zgcdAAoGrYKyHxkaLJvwAZFDO2jR0jCx6htxQAETwUKCQUGCs6KwAthB06FAA7kpQTLZgYPL6EAyxglDGAL4AlA21ddKt0iJ5UKrqzsZsQtWxjVAA9KNU6LkAgugA5rZZSMBQcCiJ4NAA5P2eRcDo+khzklB1W1D6LEhwK0pM+nNIrABG8tCOKWmZ2Rir60ltlEGFAgvE4Btkql0lkcvlCsVSuVKrEtgA6DoQLo9DS7IQ2I5zM64PoDOJxRrjVYAayAA)

Comment: How can we handle this when a function _expects no arguments_?

Comment: Answered my own question on this thread focused on _functions_ https://stackoverflow.com/a/65502037/565877

Answer (score 5):

To update this for TypeScript 3.8.3 you can simplify this:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends unknown ? 0 : never];

// Usage in a class:
class Test<P = "No type parameter was supplied"> {
  constructor(data: NoInfer<P>) {}
}

new Test({ a: " "}) // err Argument of type '{ a: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '"No type parameter was supplied"'.
new Test<{ a: string }>({ a: " "})// ok

// Usage in a function:
function Foo<P = "No type parameter was supplied"> (
  data: NoInfer<P>
) {
  return undefined
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gSQHYDMICcA8AVAfFAXigG1sBdUqCAD2AiQBMBnKAVyQGsk4B3JKAPxQADFABcUJBABuGMgG4AUAGMANgEMmLbBCbBMABUJQARPCihIUMOvTqAthDrooPTVCaswYVQEsIDCb4AN6KUFDKcEh66KzKwHDoABQM6sDqEvDIaFgGuACUUMEAvoqlilI8UDp6ScFQGaamxYUA9K1U6C4AgugA5qyOSMBQcCgW4NAA5PWNMb5IffJQxVNQvizcI5pMvn1I6gBGqtAJ1rYOThij45bTZnATVjZ2js6u7p7efgEmUwB0FQgVRq+lmEnmixWuDqDQkJma+Xaow4QA)

Comment: Do you mind explaining how the `NonInfer` type works? And is there a way to improve the error message? This way it says "TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'." where `string` comes from my particular use case.

Comment: Essentially `NoInfer` is using `T extends unknown` to check that a type is provided. If no type is provided, then it resolves to `never` which will throw an error as you stated. There we're using `P = "No type parameter was supplied"` to add to the error message. Did you play around with the TypeScript playground script? Do you have an example of your use case?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Oleg's answer from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57683742/226844

We want to have the generic parameter default to *never* when it is not explicitly specified, so that an error is raised.  But when we do this:

```js
function foo <T=never> (bar: T) {}

foo("hello")  //doesn't raise error because TypeScript infers T=string from type of 'bar'
```

The following trick works by preventing TypeScript from being able to infer T from the type of 'bar'.

```js
function foo <T=never, U extends T=T> (bar: U) {}

foo("hello")  //raises error because T=never
```