# Typescript required function type argument

Tags: typescript

I want a function that *requires* a type parameter be provided:

```
function foo<T>(key: keyof T): keyof T {
  return key;
}

foo<TypeWithoutAbc>('abc') // error
foo<TypeWithAbc>('abc') // no error
foo('abc'); // no error - why not?!
```

I would expect foo('abc') to cause an error because I didn't supply a type - how can I make the type required or otherwise accomplish what I'm trying to do here, which is make sure a string I pass exists as a property of a provided type?

Is this possible?

I tried <T = never> but it doesn't work, and instead it almost assumes the function argument is determining the type T and I get this when I mouseover foo('abc')

```
foo('abc');

function foo<{
    abc: any;
}>(key: "abc"): "abc"
```

Comment: Use a default for the generic that cannot be fulfilled, like `<T = never>`

Comment: @IngoBürk I tried that and it doesn't work either

Comment: I believe this will answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/57744230/3857837

Comment: @Yuval Thank you but I couldn't get this to work in my case. My function uses an argument whose type is the "keyof" the type parameter. I tried it many different ways, but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with an second generic type, that defaults to `keyof T`:

```
function foo<T, S extends keyof T = keyof T>(key: S): S {
  return key;
}
```

Comment: Ahh good thanks - this does result in the expected outcome!

foo<TypeWithoutAbc>('abc') // error
foo<TypeWithAbc>('abc') // no error
foo('abc') // error - nice!

One caveat is I lose the hinting from vscode that hints at acceptable argument value, which I get using the class solution.

Comment: Well the caveat with the class solution is, that you're using a class instead of function ;)

Comment: Yes, that's quite true!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to get this behavior is to utilize a class instead of a function.

```
class TypeChecker<T> {
  foo(key: keyof T & string) {
    return key as string;
  }
}

new TypeChecker<TypeWithoutAbc>().foo('abc') // error
new TypeChecker<TypeWithAbc>().foo('abc') // no error
new TypeChecker().foo('abc') // error - nice!!
```